# Is 立つ in 顔が立つ is always imperfective? If so why?

Tags: meaning, etymology, idioms, aspect

I understand that the word [立つ](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/137174/meaning/m0u/) has various meanings, but basically can be used to describe a state (for inanimate and animate objects) as well as a process (for animate objects). To describe a state for inanimate objects both: 立つ and 立っている seem to be accepted forms (ビルが立つ, ビルが立っている).

Now, an idiomatic expression [顔が立つ](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/37556/meaning/m0u/) is undoubtedly used to describe a state of "keeping one's face".

**The form 顔が立っている does not seem to be recognised.
is my observation wrong?**

What exactly does 立つ mean in this context and why the form 立っている is incorrect? Is it really a state, or could it be a response to some kind of a ..."periodic test"? Like "whenever I look at him, his response is 顔が立つ thus he is a man of honour"?

If the form 顔が立っている is incorrect, how does 立つ in 顔が立つ differ from 立つ in 腹が立つ, where 腹が立っている is also recognised and used form?

Comment: It's not particularly incorrect to interpret 顔が立っている as that meaning (e.g. 今は、かろうじて顔が立っている), and I don't really think 顔が立つ stands for a state. In most cases, 顔が立つ is used in conditional, like そうすれば、私の顔も立つ.

Comment: Well... it is described by 保つ, in that case maybe I misinterpret the meaning of 保つ if it was not a state.

Comment: 顔が立つ is synonymous to 面目を保つことができる. If you regard it as  a somewhat state, maybe it's that.

Answer (score 2):

As user4092 suggests in the comments, I don't think 顔が立っている is particularly incorrect. It's just not frequently said. Some actual examples from the internet:

- 彼らの頑張りで、こちらの**顔が立っている**のだから。
- 嫁が親戚付き合いを自然にこなしてくれるので、俺と俺の親の**顔が立っている**。
- その芸能事務所のマネージャーがただそのモデルなりタレントの子達にたいしては**顔が立っている**だけって事でしょう。

---

顔が立つ is perhaps more like an action rather than a state, similar to the English *to save face*. Then it follows that you don't often say “my face is **being saved/kept**”.

- こうすれば部長の顔が立つ *This way we'll **save** the manager's face*
- こうすると部長の顔が立たない *This will make the manager **lose** face*

I can think of some other 〜が立つ idioms that are also less likely to be used in 〜立っている form:

- 歯が立たない *insurmountable*
- 角が立つ *harsh*
- 口が立つ *eloquent*